# Java 8 : Resultset.getBigDecimal error with NUMBER(x,0) value

Tags: java, oracle, java-8

I am facing a strange error with Java code which runs correctly in Java 6, and now compiled and run in Java 8 throws an "SQLException: Invalid column index".

The SQL value in my table is of type : `NUMBER(2,0)`, which is in fact an integer value if I understand it well.

The code which worked in Java 6 is :

```
BigDecimal idPointHoraire = oResultset.getBigDecimal("ID_POINT_HORAIRE");
```

In Java 8, I have to go with intermediate integer :

```
BigDecimal idPointHoraire = new BigDecimal(oResultset.getInt("ID_POINT_HORAIRE"));
```

The question is : Why this behavior now in Java 8, when it was correct in Java 6 ?

Comment: Oracle's `NUMBER` type maps to Java's `BigDecimal` according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm).

Comment: Either the API or JDBC driver may have changed over the last several years.  Treating the `ID_POINT_HORAIRE` column as an int seems incorrect based on what I have seen, but maybe you were getting away with it in an earlier version.

Comment: The JRE only provides interfaces, so updating the JRE has no impact on the behavior of the actual `ResultSet` implementation of a particular JDBC driver. Learning how particular driver vendors interpret the API was always fun, even before Java 6…

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : Perhaps not so clear about the mapping ! I just found this [mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/datacc.htm#JJDBC28365) significantly different , and this [note](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/datacc.htm#JJDBC28367). This, at least, explains that my solution works !

Comment: Please ask only a single question per question. Your second question seems to be unrelated to your primary question and would better be asked as a new and separate question, including a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, done. But now, my answer seems a little bit odd as I answer to the fact that there was an error not mentioned in the question... :).

Answer (score 0):

While "NUMBER(2,0)" intuitively is an Integer to you, it is still a decimal datatype; you've simply limited the number of places past the decimal to 0.  So, if this behavior has changed, well, it was maybe just corrected.

If you really want the database column to be an integer... well, make it an INTEGER oracle type.

BigDecimal is what is supposed to map the NUMBER data type, and it is likely implemented in the driver.  You could experiment with downgrading your oracle driver and see if that changes anything.

Comment: In fact it is the contrary : with java 6 the mapping was from Oracle NUMBER(2,0) to java BigDecimal, in java 8 the mapping is from Oracle NUMBER(2,0) to java Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the workaround to the inconsistent behavior of retrieving number types from Oracle number of the form NUMBER(X,0) to Java BigDecimal was to write a small method :

```
    public BigDecimal getBigDecimalSafe(ResultSet resultSet, String columnName) throws SQLException{
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = null;
    if(resultSet.getString(columnName) != null){
        bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(resultSet.getString(columnName));
    }
    return bigDecimal;
}
```

The intermediate resultSet.getString never fails to retrieve the value, being it integer or decimal.